# Adding text values in container in x++

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have a AttributeTextValue field that stores value for the attributes, The values are in following format , 001,002,003 and so on , and one single attribute can contain multiple values seperated by comma  such as

```
AttributeValue = 001,002,003
```

and to split each of the text I have used str2con and this stores each value seperated by comma in a container , but issue I am facing is that str2con convert the text value to str and stores strings in container as follows : 1,2,3 but I want it to be same as 001,002 and 003 . How to accomplish this can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str2con(value, ',', false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.str2con.aspx) with parameter `_convertNumericToInt64` as `false`.

With this parameter container elements won't be converted to integer.

Comment: Thank You , exactly what i wanted